# Angular getParams from other individual component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, angular7, angular7-router

Only Getting params.get("id")  from correspond page component, Coudnt access params id from other individual components (headerComponent)

*It is Angular 7*

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>

app.module.ts
app-routing.module.ts (parent route)

common/
   --header.component.ts

projects/
  components-folder
    --component1
    --component2
  --projects.module.ts
  --projects-routing.module.ts (child route)
```

It's working with these code from a correspondent component but not working from headerComponent

```
//Its worked only correspond component only 

 this.activatedRoute.paramMap.subscribe( params => {
      this.idname  = params.get("id");
      console.log( this.idname );
    });
```

If it's possible then Can I get params from other individual directives also?

Comment: yes because your header component is not a part of routing so it doesn't know anything about the active router. you need to use @Output for it where you can set the parameter in correspondent component and emit the event from it.

Comment: Yes understand , Any solution brother @DhavalPatel

Comment: yes updated my comment

Comment: got my point or you need a demo of it ?

Comment: Yes, I am searching for examples on google

Comment: @DhavalPatel Can I get the example code ?

Comment: sure give me 10 min